# Assembly 'ClosedXML, Version=0.76.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fd1eb21b62ae805b' uses 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml,

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, closedxml

I have updated my asp.net mvc 4 project into mvc 5 by using below mentioned link.But after that it gives below error on `ClosedXML` dll. Could you tell me how to sort out that issue ? Thanks in advance.

[How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

```
Error   184 Assembly 'ClosedXML, Version=0.76.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=fd1eb21b62ae805b' uses 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, 
Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has 
a higher version than referenced assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, 
Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'   
D:\Project\trunk\Api\bin\ClosedXML.dll  API
```

Comment: Check the version of your DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll

Comment: @Raidri Yes,That is the issue.I have updated it by using nuget.Now it's working.Thanks.Can you put that as an answer ? Then I can close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message you have different version of **DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll** and should update the old versions.

[image]